# how to convert a fraction to float in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a string `"1/16"`  I want to convert it to float and multiply it by `45`.  However, I dont get the desired results.

I am trying in `script/console`

```
>> "1/16".to_f
=> 1.0
>> "1/16".to_f*45
=> 45.0
```

how can i get the desired result of `2.81`

Bigger picture: 
I have a drop down like this:

```
<%=select_tag :volume, options_for_select(["", "1 g", "1/16 oz", "1/8 oz","1/4 oz",
"1/2 oz", "1 oz", "1/8 lb", "1/4 lb", "Single", "Multi 5" ], "N/A") %>
```

whenever user selects `oz` value then i want to multiply it to 45

so i do:

```
first, *rest = params[:volume].to_s.split(/ /)
if rest.first=="oz"
    @indprodprice = @prods.orig_price.to_i*first.to_f*28.3495
else 
    @indprodprice = @prods.orig_price.to_i*first.to_f*453.59237
end
```

Comment: i cant. i am getting a string from submitting a form in my html page.

Comment: I notice your drop down involves units as well as fractions. You might want to try the ruby-units gem, which handles both... https://github.com/olbrich/ruby-units

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like you're going to have to parse the fraction yourself. This will work on fractions and whole numbers, but not mixed numbers (ie: 1½ will not work.)

```
class String
  def to_frac
    numerator, denominator = split('/').map(&:to_f)
    denominator ||= 1
    numerator/denominator
  end
end

"1/16".to_frac * 45
```

Comment: It's some ruby short hand. `map(&:method)` works out to `map {|obj| obj.method}`

Answer (score 17):

Use Rational

```
>> (Rational(*("1/16".split('/').map( &:to_i )))*45).to_f
=> 2.8125
```

Comment: I'd use that as it keeps maximum precision until you convert to float.

Comment: You can just do `(Rational("1/16") * 45).to_f`

Answer (score 10):

@Farrel was right, and since Ruby 1.9 includes Rational and String has a `to_r`-method things are easier:

```
puts ("1/16".to_r * 45).to_f  #=> 2.8125
puts ("1/16".to_r * 45).to_f.round(2) #=> 2.81
```

In 2.0 it became even easier with a rational literal:

```
1/16r # => (1/16)
```