# Converting String "2½" (two and a half) into 2.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, character-encoding, floating-point

Right now I'm building a small app that imports data from a spreadsheet and due to the nature of the original entry, there is a string being read in that has values such as 8½, 2½, etc.

My goal with a simple function is to convert 2½ into float 2.5, for example.

I've tried the .to_f method but that has left me with a weird value of 2.02½.

Any insight or suggestions here would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Can the source spreadsheet be changed? If the field type can be changed to decimal/numeric I would think you can avoid that entirely

Comment: It can, and I was weighing whether it would be faster to do it programmatically or not. I have 17 spreadsheets with around 17 rows in each. It really shouldn't be much to change

Comment: Automation is respectable for sure! I personally am not aware of how to accomplish this, but this thread indicates it may not be easily accomplished (with 2½ specifically) => http://stackoverflow.com/a/2259624/691986  If this is the *only* case of a mixed number, a mix of that solution with some specific code handling would probably get you where you need to be

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unicode only supports a [small number of vulgar fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_Forms) so a simple lookup table will do the trick:

```
# You might want to double check this mapping
vulgar_to_float = {
    "\u00BC" => 1.0 / 4.0,
    "\u00BD" => 1.0 / 2.0,
    "\u00BE" => 3.0 / 4.0,
    "\u2150" => 1.0 / 7.0,
    "\u2151" => 1.0 / 9.0,
    "\u2152" => 1.0 /10.0,
    "\u2153" => 1.0 / 3.0,
    "\u2154" => 2.0 / 3.0,
    "\u2155" => 1.0 / 5.0,
    "\u2156" => 2.0 / 5.0,
    "\u2157" => 3.0 / 5.0,
    "\u2158" => 4.0 / 5.0,
    "\u2159" => 1.0 / 6.0,
    "\u215A" => 5.0 / 6.0,
    "\u215B" => 1.0 / 8.0,
    "\u215C" => 3.0 / 8.0,
    "\u215D" => 5.0 / 8.0,
    "\u215E" => 7.0 / 8.0,
    "\u2189" => 0.0 / 3.0,
}
```

Then, a little bit of regex wrangling to pull your "number" apart:

```
s = "2½"
_, int_part, vulgar_part = *s.match(/(\d+)?(\D+)?/)
```

And finally, put them together taking care to properly deal with possible `nil`s from the regex:

```
float_version = int_part.to_i + vulgar_to_float[vulgar_part].to_f
```

Remember that `nil.to_i` is `0` and `nil.to_f` is `0.0`.

Comment: -1, reimplements Unicode poorly. (For example, you missed 2189.)

Comment: @Joe: And what is `"\u2189"`? Zero. So it has no effect on the result. And there are only [19 vulgar fractions in Unicode](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt), Roman numerals and other number forms are irrelevant to this question.

Answer (score 7):

Substitute the halves with `".5"`

```
input = "2½"
input.gsub!("½", ".5")
input.to_f # => 2.5
```

As an aside, make sure you really want to use floats and not something like [BigDecimal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html).

[Here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) is a page explaining the problem with floats (it's Python, but Ruby and many other languages represent floats the same way, and thus have the same issues).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `input.gsub!("½", ".5")`?

Comment: Being specific makes it easy to understand. It is significantly easier to understand than any of the other answers. Regardless, no general problem has been specified, so a general answer must be a guess. Guessing at requirements is historically unreliable (think YAGNI and "the simplest thing that could possibly work").

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @muistooshort's answer, I'd use a hash as a lookup table, but I'd take advantage of `sub`:

```
# encoding: UTF-8

LOOKUP = {
  "½" => 1.0/2,
  # ...
  "⅞" => 7.0/8,
}

LOOKUP_REGEX = Regexp.union(LOOKUP.keys) # => /½|⅞/ 

'2½'.sub(LOOKUP_REGEX) { |m| LOOKUP[m].to_s[1..-1] } # => "2.5" 
'2⅞'.sub(LOOKUP_REGEX) { |m| LOOKUP[m].to_s[1..-1] } # => "2.875"
```

To make it more convenient and prettier:

```
class String
  def v_to_f
    sub(LOOKUP_REGEX) { |m| LOOKUP[m].to_s[1..-1] }
  end
end

'2½'.v_to_f # => "2.5" 
'2⅞'.v_to_f # => "2.875"
```

Comment: -1, similar to muistooshort's answer, you're reimplementing Unicode standard data poorly.

Comment: Why don't you explain your concern and provide a solution? Marking the answers down, and quoting the Unicode tables doesn't help the OP find a solution.

Comment: The Unicode tables are the solution. You parse the Unicode tables. This gives you the correct value for each codepoint.

Comment: Parsing the Unicode table would provide "1/2", which in Ruby would be `1/2==0`. Is that preferable to `1.0/2==0.5`? Your suggestion is not workable.

Comment: My solution assumes basic knowledge of Ruby (like, how to evaluate a simple fraction even though the text of both numerator and denominator are provided without a decimal point), which if the asker has already loaded a spreadsheet doesn't seem like a bad assumption.