# Convert object into float (6½ to 6.5)

Tags: python, pandas

With this attempt `df['Total'] = df['Total'].astype('float')` returns `could not convert string to float: '5½'`. I tried `.str.split()` as well but that did not work either.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Total': ['6', '5', '5', '5½', '5½', '6½', '6½']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Comment: The `½` is a special unicode character, and isn't recognized as 3 characters, a fraction, or as a numeric value.  You might be able use a string replace method to change it to '.5'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051560/converting-string-2%C2%BD-two-and-a-half-into-2-5 create a map

Comment: @hpaulj funny that I tried string replace and is not working on it either

Comment: I kind of understand what they did with the regex in the other question, I'm just not sure how to convert it to fit my dataframe

Comment: you can do `df['Total'] = df['Total'].str.replace('½','.5').astype(float)`

Comment: I have put the code as answer, if it helped you consider up-voting & accepting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace) to replace '½' with '.5' & then use `astype(float)` to convert the values to `float`. Code below.

```
df['Total'] = df['Total'].str.replace('½','.5').astype(float)
```

**Input**

```
    Total
0   6
1   5
2   5
3   5½
4   5½
5   6½
6   6½
```

**Output**

```
    Total
0   6.0
1   5.0
2   5.0
3   5.5
4   5.5
5   6.5
6   6.5
```